# Check password is correct having md5 hashed in database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a password for a user in my database that is hashed with md5 and I am trying to make a login to check if the password is correct, how can I do this. I imagine I need to convert the string of the password input to md5 to check if it is the same?

Comment: To start with, your database doesn't normally contains just hashed password: normally a salt and other parts (for example the user name) are included in the string before hash. This should be documented somewhere with the DB. Note also that md5 hasn't been much used in the last decade due to its weakness

Comment: @DenysSéguret alright, because I made the user in the databse, I dont want a register page since it will only be one person operating the site so I did md5 generator but I should instead use mysql own hash or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct.

You don't want the password stored as plain text. So you can [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) it and store the salted version in the database.
Each time the operator attempts login, salt his input and compare that salt to the value stored in the database.

You can hash the password via MD5 and store the hash in the database, hashing user login input and comparing, as described above. It's not recommended, although better than storing plain text passwords.

Comment: sorry for late reply, ye in my db the password is hashed as md5 but since it is hashed I need to convert the string that the  user put in from string to md5 hased and the ncompare and I do not know how to go about that. I seem to be bad at googling or just missing soemthign xD

Answer (score 0):

You can use the password() function of MySQL that will store it as a hash using whatever it's hashing scheme is.

```
INSERT INTO `your_db_name`.`your_user_table_name` VALUES 'submitted_username','other_submitted_values',password('submitted_password');
```